# Char pointer seems to get 'stuck' at slash-zero? ('\0')

Tags: c, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

I'm solving a problem in C where I'm given a sequence of bytes in memory that represents game results between two teams, something like this format: *"manchester 40 chelsea;chelsea 43 arsenal\0"* So each result starts with the name of the first team, then a space, then their score represented with a single byte, then the second team's score also as one byte, another space, and the name of the second team. Results are separated with semicolons, but the final one ends with '\0'. This is the code I have written:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    char *team1;
    int score1;
    char *team2;
    int score2;
} gameResult;

char *nameCopy(void* results, char terminate) {
    char *ptr = (char*)results;
    int len = 0;
    while (*ptr != '\0' && *ptr != terminate) {
        len++;
        ptr++;
    }
    char *res = malloc(len + 1);
    memcpy(res, results, len);
    res[len] = '\0';
    
    return res;
}

gameResult readGameResult(void* results) {
    gameResult res;
    char* ptr = (char*)results;
    res.team1 = nameCopy(ptr, ' ');
    ptr += strlen(res.team1) + 1;
    res.score1 = *ptr;
    ptr++;
    res.score2 = *ptr;

    res.team2 = nameCopy(ptr + 2, ';');
    printf("%s, %d, %d, %s\n", res.team1, res.score1, res.score2, res.team2);
    return res;

}

int main() {
    // manchester 41 chelsea;chelsea 32 arsenal;arsenal 23 manchester\0
    char results[63] = "manchester 04 chelsea;chelsea 32 arsenal;arsenal 23 manchester";
    results[11] = 4;
    results[12] = 0;
    results[30] = 3;
    results[31] = 2;
    results[49] = 2;
    results[50] = 3;
    results[62] = '\0';

    char *gres = strdup(results);
    readGameResult(gres);

    return 0;   
}
```

There seems to be an issue with me storing the single-byte scores as chars. The code works for every instance except when one of the scores is 0. I'm guessing this has something to do with the fact that the ascii value 0 corresponds to the null terminating character. But I still don't see why this should cause a problem, because with the line `res.team2 = nameCopy(ptr + 2, ';');` I'm supposed to be advancing past the 0 character but the nameCopy function still seems to receive a pointer to '/0'. The above code produces the following output:
`"manchester, 4, 0, \r\n"`

Comment: `40` is not a single byte, it's two bytes.

Comment: @Barmar I'm aware of that? that represents the result 4-0 where 4 and 0 are written in single bytes

Comment: You're storing the ASCII character code in `score1` and `score2`, not the numeric value 4 and 0.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and create a [mre]. Add a `main` function that prepares hard-coded input data and calls your functions to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Why don't you use `strtok()`?

Comment: I know football scores are normally pretty low, but what happens if someone scores more than 9 goals?

Comment: There's no ASCII value `0`. There's a character `'0'` which has the ASCII value 48.

Comment: Or is it actually stored in the file as `manchester \4\0`? That shouldn't cause a problem because the loop in `nameCopy()` stops at the space character.

Comment: @barmar the problem said that each score is represented in a single byte, as in the actual bit representation. That's what I tried to do when I designed my own input. I just wrote "40" in the example for clarity

Comment: I assume that the problem lies in code that you have not shown. `res.score1 = *ptr;` let me think that you are reading a file, and that the file was produced by another code. There is nothing wrong in writing null bytes into files, but it must be done cautiously. I am sorry, but without a [mre] I cannot guess more.

Comment: It's confusing because you wrote `\0` for the terminating null byte. So either show byte values as `\n` or not.

Comment: @SergeBallesta i added the main function with the input

Comment: And the culprit is `char *gres = strdup(results);`! `strdup` will only copy up to the first null character so `gres` is not a full copy of you `results` array. BTW, as a byte value, `0` and `'\0'` are exactly the same thing...

Comment: I strongly suggest that you compile with `-g -fsanitize=address,undefined`. See [here](https://godbolt.org/z/9v6xTzTdj) why.

Comment: Oh I figured it out, it's the strdup() call thinking the 0 value is the end of the string. Thanks guys

Comment: @SergeBallesta thank you

Comment: @liz "strdup() call thinking the 0 value is the end of the string" --> In C, all _strings_ end with a _null character_ (`'\0'`), so 0 _is_ the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

It's like you want

```
    results[11] = '4';
    results[12] = '0';
    results[30] = '3';
    results[31] = '2';
    results[49] = '2';
    results[50] = '3';
    results[62] = '\0';
```

Thus the numbers as characters rather than the control codes. '0' is 48 but displays a zero.